# OpenAPI3 definition for multipart request doesn't show example value or schema in Swagger or Azure

Tags: openapi, azure-api-management, swagger-editor

I'm writing some OpenAPI specs for an API I'm developing, and noticed that both the Swagger editor I'm using (editor.swagger.com) and the automatically generated "Developer portal" in my Azure API Management instance don't seem to show any details for a JSON object inside a multipart/form-data request:

[image: Swagger Editor screenshot of problem]

I didn't get any parse errors, so I was expecting the JSON object to have the example / schema selector under it so developers can look at the object structure more easily, like is default for other types of requests:

[image: Swagger Editor screenshot of expected result]

I tried adding an example value to the "FileUploadData" schema that the object in the multipart request was using, but it didn't change anything. Is there a way I can force it to display those details and make the schema button show up, or is this not supported on any (or most) OpenAPI viewers?

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: SFTP Functions
  description: Import from "test-functionapp" Function App
  version: '1.0'
servers:
  - url: example.com
paths:
  /uploadfile:
    post:
      summary: UploadFile
      description: UploadFile
      operationId: post-uploadfile
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                sftpdata:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileUploadData'
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The file was uploaded successfully.
components:
  schemas:
    FileUploadData:
      type: object
      properties:
        Url:
          type: string
        Username:
          type: string
        Password:
          type: string
        Port:
          type: string
        Path:
          type: string
      example:
        Url: "hello"
        Username: "test"
        Password: "password"
        Port: "2022"
        Path: "/"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5169)

Comment: That's unfortunate, looks like this is just an unresolved issue. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score -1):

As per the [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-api-import-restrictions) `OpenAPI 3.0.3 and 3.1.0` (import only) are supported.

The "form" type parameters are not supported. You can use policy to decode and validate `application/x-www-form-url` encoded and `application/form-data` payloads.

You have not defined the schema for the JSON object inside it for the `multipart/form-data` request body. To display the value or schema for the `JSON object`, you need to define the schema for it in the components section of your `OpenAPI` spec.

Sample schema for the JSON object

```
components:
  schemas:
    SftpData:
      type: object
      properties:
        Url:
          type: string
        Username:
          type: string
        Password:
          type: string
        Port:
          type: string
        Path:
          type: string
      example:
        Url: "hello"
        Username: "test"
        Password: "password"
        Port: "20345"
        Path: "/"
```

You can check this schema in the schema for the `multipart/form-data` request body.

```
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data:
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          sftpdata:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/SftpData'
          file:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

For further information refer to [GitHub Issue #5169](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5169) and [Validate content policy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/validate-content-policy)

Comment: What do you mean I haven't defined the schema for the JSON object? It looks like the sample schema and request body definition you provided are nearly identical to the ones I included with my question - the only difference I could see is that you used "sample" instead of "example" in the schema, but "sample" isn't a valid keyword. Also, the screenshot you sent is from the "Try it out" view, not the schema view. I'd like users to be able to view the schema if possible. Thanks!